# Play a sequence of remote audio files using Expo AV in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I'm creating an app in React Native that is looking to playback a list of audio messages that have been left for a user. I'm attempting to do it currently using Expo AV. I'm returning an array of audio messages (which are really mp3 file paths on a cdn) and I've got it working to play a single remote audio file by hard coding it to read the first item in the array (see code below):

```
const HomeComponent = ({ user }) => {

    const soundObject = new Audio.Sound();

    const loadAudio = async () => {

        try {
          await soundObject.loadAsync({ uri: user.messages[0].path /* url for your audio file */ });
        } catch (e) {
          console.log('ERROR Loading Audio', e);
        }
    }

    if (user)
        loadAudio();

    const play = async () => {
        if(user.messages) {
            console.log("Playing Messages!")
            const status = await soundObject.playAsync();
            console.log(status)
        } else {
            console.log("No Messages!")
        }
    }

    const stop = () => {
        console.log("Messages stopped!")
        soundObject.pauseAsync();
    }

    return (
        <View style={{
            flex: 1,
            backgroundColor: 'blue',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center'
        }}>
            <Background style={styles.background} width={width} />
            <FacePlate style={styles.face} width={width} />
            {user ? <Text style={styles.messageCount}>{user.messages.length}</Text> : null}
            <View style={styles.buttons}>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                    play();
                }}>
                    <PlayButton />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                    stop();
                }}>
                    <StopButton />
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    background: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0
    },
    face: {
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom: 0,
        left: 0
    },
    messageCount: {
        fontSize: 100,
        position: 'absolute',
        color: 'red',
        bottom: 350
    },
    buttons: {
        position: 'absolute',
        bottom: 20,
        flexDirection: 'row',
        flex: 1
    }
});

export default HomeComponent;
```

What I'd really like to do is create an array of soundObjects by mapping the results of user.messages and then iterate through that array and play each of the messages in sequence. Any help or direction would be much much appreciates.

Thanks,

Evan

Comment: Look at: https://github.com/expo/playlist-example/blob/master/README.md